# Property in type is not assignable to the same property in base type typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs

```
export type RemoveGroupRecipientParams = {
 id: number;
 removeUserId: number;
 issuerId: number;
};
```

And

```
async removeGroupRecipient(params: RemoveGroupRecipientParams) {
  const { issuerId, removeUserId, id } = params;
  const userToBeRemoved = await this.userService.findUser({
    id: removeUserId,
  });
  if (!userToBeRemoved)
    throw new HttpException('User cannot be removed', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  const group = await this.groupService.findGroupById(id);
  if (!group) throw new GroupNotFoundException();
  if (group.creator.id !== issuerId) throw new NotGroupOwnerException();
  if (group.creator.id === removeUserId)
    throw new HttpException(
      'Cannot remove yourself as owner',
      HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
    );
  group.users = group.users.filter((u) => u.id !== removeUserId);
  const savedGroup = await this.groupService.saveGroup(group);
  return { group: savedGroup, user: userToBeRemoved };
}
```

removing `await` from `const savedGroup = await this.groupService.saveGroup(group);` this line throwing the error

```
error TS2416: Property 'removeGroupRecipient' in type 'GroupRecipientService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IGroupRecipientService'.
  Type '(params: RemoveGroupRecipientParams) => Promise<{ group: Promise<Group>; user: User; }>' is not assignable to type '(params: RemoveGroupRecipientParams) => Promise<RemoveGroupUserResponse>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ group: Promise<Group>; user: User; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<RemoveGroupUserResponse>'.
      Type '{ group: Promise<Group>; user: User; }' is not assignable to type 'RemoveGroupUserResponse'.
        Types of property 'group' are incompatible.
          Type 'Promise<Group>' is missing the following properties from type 'Group': id, users, creator, messages, and 3 more.

43   async removeGroupRecipient(params: RemoveGroupRecipientParams) {
```

RemoveGroupRecipientParams do not have any promise in this then why this is happening?

Also

```
export interface IGroupRecipientService {
  addGroupRecipient(
    params: AddGroupRecipientParams,
  ): Promise<AddGroupUserResponse>;
  removeGroupRecipient(
    params: RemoveGroupRecipientParams,
  ): Promise<RemoveGroupUserResponse>;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `IGroupRecipientService` interface? Looks like it expects a `Group` but you return a `Promise<Group>`

Comment: I added `IGroupRecipientService` in question. Please check.

Comment: can you show your `RemoveGroupUserResponse` type ?

Comment: Ah, what is your `this.groupService.saveGroup`? What does that return?